# VB.net Fill Textbox with HTML string

Tags: html, vb.net, textbox

I have a string from an HTML enabled email of something like so:

```
</div><span color="red">Hi how are you?!</span></div><table><tr><td>Company Information</td></tr></table>
```

and so on [its a long string of stuff but you get the idea. There are `<div>`..`<spans>`..`<table>` and so forth.

**I want to display the text in the text box formatted like html [which will format it based on the `<table>`..`<span>` and so forth while removing the actual text of `<span>` and so forth from the textbox's text.**

I need this to happen because I get a page error because it reads the `<span>` and etc as being a security issue.

My current way of reading the whole text and removing the issues are like so:

```
        If Not DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) Is DBNull.Value Then
            Dim bodyInitial As String = DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()

            Dim newbody As String = bodyInitial.Replace("<br>", vbNewLine)
            newbody = newbody.Replace("<b>", "")
            newbody = newbody.Replace("</b>", "")
            Bodylisting.Text = newbody
        End If
```

I tried to encorporate the following:

```
Dim bodyInitial As String = DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
        Dim myEncodedString As String
        ' Encode the string.
        myEncodedString = bodyInitial.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(bodyInitial)

        Dim myWriter As New StringWriter()
        ' Decode the encoded string.
        HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(bodyInitial, myWriter)
```

but I get errors with HTTpUtility and strings

**Question:**

So my question is, is there a way to actually see the HTML formatting and fill the textbox that way, or do I have to stick with my `.Replace` method?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Bodylisting" runat="server" style="float:left; margin:10px; padding-bottom:500px;" Width="95%" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you investigate [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  This library includes a parser giving you the ability to 'select' the `<span>` tags.  Once you have them, you can strip them out, or grab the InnerHtml and do further processing.  This is an example of how I do something similar with it.

```
    Private Shared Function StripHtml(html As String, xPath As String) As String
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html)
        If xPath.Length > 0 Then
            Dim invalidNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath)
            If Not invalidNodes Is Nothing Then
                For Each node As HtmlNode In invalidNodes
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, True)
                Next
            End If
        End If
        Return htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo()


    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and references. I will play with the following coding. Once again, I appreciate it!

Comment: Also, if you don't mind me asking, what `Import` do you use to define `New HtmlDocument()` ?

Comment: Glad I could help  `Imports HtmlAgilityPack` will let you get to `HtmlDocument`

Comment: When I put `Imports HtmlAgilityPack` HtmlAgilityPack has a green line under it with no suggestions as if it doesn't exist

Comment: Did you download the file and add a reference to the DLL to your project?

Comment: Not sure what you mean download file; however, when looking in "add reference" I don't see it listed. Not sure if it is listed as a different name?

Comment: You'll need to download the library from CodePlex https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ - the same link as above.  When you download the zip file, extract the files from inside the NetXX folder corresponding to the .Net Framework version your project is compiling for.  This is the DLL you'll add the refrerence to.  I apologize - I assumed these steps were already done/understood.  But this should get you going.

Comment: Ok I understand now! Thanks